# Insert Update on Duplicate this Query based on Session ID

Tags: php, session

My system gets the user to enter a score which is then added to the database via this php. It will only update if a value has already been inserted (currently) - is there a way using an Insert Update on Duplicate using this syntax allowing the score to update based on the SESSION ID ?

[image: My Database]

```
<?php
include("php/functions.php");
include('connections/conn.php');
$userID = $_SESSION["userID"];


//echo "all good here";



$newsselfesteemscore = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['selfesteemscore']);

/**$insertquery1 = "UPDATE selfesteemscore SET selestscore = '$newsselfesteemscore' , UserID = '$userID' ";**/

$insertquery1 = "UPDATE selfesteemscore SET selestscore = '$newsselfesteemscore' WHERE UserID = '$userID' ";

$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $insertquery1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Attempt below

```html
$newsselfesteemscore = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['selfesteemscore']);


$insertquery1 = "INSERT INTO selfesteemscore(selestscore, UserID) VALUES('$newsselfesteemscore', '$userID')"
        . " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE selfesteemscore SET selestscore = '$newsselfesteemscore' WHERE UserID = '$userID' "; 
var_dump(mysqli_error($conn));

$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $insertquery1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

The error I'm getting after removing the WHERE component

```html
string(0) "" You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET selestscore = '17' , UserID = '25'' at line 1
```

```html
$insertquery1 = "INSERT INTO selfesteemscore(selestscore, UserID) VALUES('$newsselfesteemscore', '$userID')"
        . " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE selfesteemscore(selestscore, UserID) VALUES ('$newsselfesteemscore' , UserID = '$userID') "; 
var_dump(mysqli_error($conn));

$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $insertquery1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

```html
string(0) "" You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(selestscore, UserID) VALUES ('17' , UserID = '25')' at line 1
```

Comment: Use a WHERE condition. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html. Or for duplicate keys, make sure you have a unique key. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: @aynber I've used a WHERE condition but I need it to INSERT UPDATE on DUPLICATE values where User ID = SESSION (User ID)

Comment: Make sure user_id is a unique column, and the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` should work.  Check the second link I posted.

Comment: @aynber I've tried honestly can't get the syntax correct it keeps throwing errors

Comment: Please [edit] your post with the query you're passing and the full error message, which will help us see what's going on.

Comment: @aynber $newsselfesteemscore = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['selfesteemscore']);


$insertquery1 = "INSERT INTO selfesteemscore(selestscore, UserID) VALUES('$newsselfesteemscore', '$userID')"
        . " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE selfesteemscore SET selestscore = '$newsselfesteemscore' WHERE UserID = '$userID' "; 
var_dump(mysqli_error($conn));

$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $insertquery1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

mysqli_close($conn);
?>

Comment: Don't add the where with the ON DUPLICATE KEY. It's not compatible with the INSERT clause.

Comment: @aynber I've removed the where clause its throwing this error : string(0) "" You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET selestscore = '17' , UserID = '25'' at line 1

Comment: Remove the SET as well

Comment: @aynber re-edited still throwing syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) gives you the syntax for the INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. Your query should be like this:

```
$insertquery1 = "INSERT INTO selfesteemscore(selestscore, UserID) VALUES('$newsselfesteemscore', '$userID')"
        . " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE selestscore = '$newsselfesteemscore', UserID = '$userID' ";
```

However, if userID is the unique key, then don't update it:

```
$insertquery1 = "INSERT INTO selfesteemscore(selestscore, UserID) VALUES('$newsselfesteemscore', '$userID')"
        . " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE selestscore = '$newsselfesteemscore' ";
```